# Is Azure Azul JVM source code available in a public repository?

Tags: azure, azure-zulu, azul-zulu

http://www.azulsystems.com/products/zulu mentions the code is released on GPL + classpath exception but I didn't see any pointers to where the source code is available ?

Is it built from a branch in the public openjdk source tree or somewhere else ?

Comment: azulsystems website says to use "azure azul" as tag but that tag does not exist so i used azure as the closest thing.

Answer (score 4):

For making an Azul Zulu source request, look in the root of your Zulu installation for the readme.txt file. It contains this paragraph:

> Certain portions of this software are based on source code from
>   OpenJDK (http://openjdk.java.net/)  and  licensed  under  the GNU
>   General Public License  version  2  (GPLv2)  with   the  Classpath 
>   Exception  (http:// openjdk.java.net/legal/gplv2+ce.html).  For a
>   period of three years from the date  of your receipt  of  this 
>   software,  Azul  will  provide upon request, a complete  machine
>   readable  copy of the  source code for such portions  based  on 
>   OpenJDK on a medium  customarily used  for software interchange for a
>   charge no more  than the cost of physically performing source
>   distribution.
>
> Please email azul_openjdk@azulsystems.com for further information.

The next few lines of that file contain a version and a product ID for the Zulu build you are using. You include those in your email so we can provide to you the source snapshot corresponding to that particular build image.

As far as the choice of "medium customarily used for software interchange", over time we have used FTP and Dropbox, though recently started using WeTransfer to fulfill most requests. In your email request, you can ask for any medium you prefer.

Finally, there is no public Zulu source repository, because the source is fetched from OpenJDK. The OpenJDK project source repos are therefore the proper place to navigate, study, review, and contribute source fixes and changes. Zulu source snapshots reflect the fetch from the OpenJDK codeline that fed the particular Zulu build. They are not forks of the master branches.

These statements are common for Zulu on Azure, Zulu on Docker, Zulu from the Azul download sites (web and the Azul yum/AptGet repo) and any other place you obtained Zulu.

Matt Schuetze

Answer (score 1):

You may send a request to azul (underscore) openjdk (at) azulsystems (dot) com for a source snapshot bundle. Please indicate which Zulu version(s) you require. A download link will be emailed to you.

Comment: Is this still the case? Is this documented somewhere?